Why the video is like this after ffmpeg save RTSP stream to MP4 file?
I use ffmpeg to save an IPcam RTSP to a MP4 file, but the video have half green or gray blocks, here is the parameter:
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://192.168.0.37/live/1" -s 1920x1080 -filter:v "fps=fps=15,drawtext=text='test':fontcolor=red:fontsize=32:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -crf 36 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -an -t 10 -f mp4 tmp.mp4

and here is the strange video:

